# I can't find ASP.Net MVC application in VS 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When i click on new project, i dont see ASP.NET MVC Web Application as it describes in:

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx

does anyone know why i wouldn't see this?  I have vs 2008 sp1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download and install Asp.Net MVC from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=144444).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need to download it. It only got officially released this year. So it might be bundled in the next version. You can download it from www.asp.net/mvc/